# Embed Chart Template into Macro

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to embed applying a chart template into a macro and require help. 
I have this code for the Macro that I am using to create scatter plots:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+X

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as appropriate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

BuildChart ws, SelectRanges(ws)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

 Private Function SelectRanges(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range

 Dim rngX As Range
 Dim rngY As Range

 ws.Activate

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 On Error Resume Next

 Set rngX = Application.InputBox("Please select X values. One column.", 
 Type:=8)

 If rngX Is Nothing Then GoTo InvalidSelection

 Set rngY = Application.InputBox("Please select Y values. One column.", 
 Type:=8)

 If rngY Is Nothing Then GoTo InvalidSelection

 If rngX.Columns.Count > 1 Or rngY.Columns.Count > 1 Then GoTo 
 InvalidSelection

 On Error GoTo 0

 Set SelectRanges = Union(rngX, rngY)
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Exit Function

 InvalidSelection:
If rngX Is Nothing Or rngY Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please ensure you have selected both X and Y ranges."
ElseIf rngX.Rows.Count <> rngX.Rows.Count Then
     MsgBox "Please ensure the same number of rows are selected for X and Y 
ranges"
ElseIf rngX.Columns.Count > 1 Or rngY.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Please ensure X range has only one column and Y range has only 
one column"
Else
   MsgBox "Unspecified"
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End

End Function

Private Sub BuildChart(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef unionRng As Range)

 With ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=unionRng
End With

ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\maaro\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1.crtx")

End Sub
```

And would like to embed this code below into the above code so that it applies the template to the chart I create whenever I run this Macro. My initial guess would be to put it underneath "Private Sub BuildCharts". How would I be able to do this? Thank you.

```
       ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1.crtx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps modify `Sub BuildChart` like this:

```
Private Sub BuildChart(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef unionRng As Range)

    With ws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=unionRng
        .ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "C:\Users\maaro\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1.crtx")
    End With

End Sub
```